# "DOTWEEN ► Couldn't load Modules system" error every time I launch the game in Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

The log of the error itself, while I’m looking for a solution, I sent it here myself, maybe someone has come across, I haven’t found similar questions on the network yet, the last actions that were before this error

1. All scripts got a namespace according to their directories (the `IDE JetBrains Rider` helped in this), before that they were all united in one.
2. All services have been moved from the main directory `Assets/` to `Assets/Services/*ServiceName*` for convenience. (Is this practiced at all? Services: Google Play Services, Firebase, IronSource)

Perhaps the matter is different, this log does not tell me anything, I just see something related to the Debug Log, I will be glad if you can clarify on what basis this Log is drawn up.

```
DOTWEEN ► Couldn't load Modules system
0x00007ff6a5fa78dc (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
0x00007ff6a5faff79 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
0x00007ff6a74d3ddc (Unity) GetStacktrace
0x00007ff6a8602ee3 (Unity) DebugStringToFile
0x00007ff6a607bd76 (Unity) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log
0x0000022d4108196b (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
0x0000022d4108189b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
0x0000022d410815e0 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object)
0x0000022d410a3c75 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
0x0000022d410a3be3 (Mono JIT Code) [Debugger.cs:49] DG.Tweening.Core.Debugger:LogError (object,DG.Tweening.Tween) 
0x0000022d410a1aeb (Mono JIT Code) [DOTweenComponent.cs:54] DG.Tweening.Core.DOTweenComponent:Awake () 
0x0000022d410a11d0 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007ffa5341e660 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2816] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ffa533a2ae2 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2921] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ffa533abb3f (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2968] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff6a5e2f0f4 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff6a5e275f5 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff6a5e27a1e (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::InvokeChecked
0x00007ff6a5e94ac6 (Unity) SerializableManagedRef::CallMethod
0x00007ff6a5dd2ad4 (Unity) MonoBehaviour::CallAwake
0x00007ff6a5dd1325 (Unity) MonoBehaviour::AddToManager
0x00007ff6a5dbaf49 (Unity) ManagedMonoBehaviourRef::RebuildMonoInstanceFromScriptChange
0x00007ff6a5ea2ae8 (Unity) SerializableManagedRef::SetScript
0x00007ff6a56d3722 (Unity) SetupScriptForIManagedObjectHost
0x00007ff6a56cacf9 (Unity) AddComponentUnchecked
0x00007ff6a56ca86a (Unity) AddComponent
0x00007ff6a5d1b50b (Unity) MonoAddComponentWithType
0x00007ff6a5fdf43a (Unity) GameObject_CUSTOM_Internal_AddComponentWithType
0x0000022d40f52a56 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.GameObject:Internal_AddComponentWithType (UnityEngine.GameObject,System.Type)
0x0000022d40f52983 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.GameObject:AddComponent (System.Type)
0x0000022d40f528bb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.GameObject:AddComponent<T_REF> ()
0x0000022d410a1903 (Mono JIT Code) [DOTweenComponent.cs:262] DG.Tweening.Core.DOTweenComponent:Create () 
0x0000022d410a138b (Mono JIT Code) [DOTween.cs:207] DG.Tweening.DOTween:Init (DG.Tweening.Core.DOTweenSettings,System.Nullable`1<bool>,System.Nullable`1<bool>,System.Nullable`1<DG.Tweening.LogBehaviour>) 
0x0000022d410a0f83 (Mono JIT Code) [DOTween.cs:195] DG.Tweening.DOTween:AutoInit () 
0x0000022d410a0d6b (Mono JIT Code) [DOTween.cs:1076] DG.Tweening.DOTween:InitCheck () 
0x0000022d410a0bab (Mono JIT Code) [DOTween.cs:1084] DG.Tweening.DOTween:ApplyTo<UnityEngine.Color, UnityEngine.Color, DG.Tweening.Plugins.Options.ColorOptions> (DG.Tweening.Core.DOGetter`1<UnityEngine.Color>,DG.Tweening.Core.DOSetter`1<UnityEngine.Color>,UnityEngine.Color,single,DG.Tweening.Plugins.Core.ABSTweenPlugin`3<UnityEngine.Color, UnityEngine.Color, DG.Tweening.Plugins.Options.ColorOptions>) 
0x0000022d410a05c3 (Mono JIT Code) [DOTween.cs:495] DG.Tweening.DOTween:ToAlpha (DG.Tweening.Core.DOGetter`1<UnityEngine.Color>,DG.Tweening.Core.DOSetter`1<UnityEngine.Color>,single,single) 
0x0000022d410a03db (Mono JIT Code) [DOTweenModuleUI.cs:55] Plugins.Demigiant.DOTween.Modules.DOTweenModuleUI:DOFade (UnityEngine.UI.Graphic,single,single) 
0x0000022d410a0083 (Mono JIT Code) [GeneralNotification.cs:25] UI.General.GeneralNotification/<ShowCoroutine>d__2:MoveNext () 
0x0000022d4109e4ac (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator,intptr)
0x0000022d4109e5d7 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_object_intptr (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007ffa5341e660 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2816] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ffa533a2ae2 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2921] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ffa533abb3f (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2968] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff6a5e2f0f4 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff6a5e275f5 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff6a5dc37cf (Unity) Coroutine::Run
0x00007ff6a5ddf7ce (Unity) MonoBehaviour::TryCreateAndRunCoroutine
0x00007ff6a5dddf63 (Unity) MonoBehaviour::StartCoroutineManaged2
0x00007ff6a600e5a4 (Unity) MonoBehaviour_CUSTOM_StartCoroutineManaged2
0x0000022d4109e386 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutineManaged2 (UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour,System.Collections.IEnumerator)
0x0000022d4109e0c3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine (System.Collections.IEnumerator)
0x0000022d4109ffc3 (Mono JIT Code) [GeneralNotification.cs:19] UI.General.GeneralNotification:Show (string) 
0x0000022d4109f86b (Mono JIT Code) [GooglePlayServices.cs:59] Managers.GooglePlayServices/<>c:<Login>b__8_0 (GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.SignInStatus) 
0x0000022d4109f731 (Mono JIT Code) [PlayGamesPlatform.cs:435] GooglePlayGames.ISocialPlatform.PlayGamesPlatform/<>c__DisplayClass34_0:<Authenticate>b__2 (GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.SignInStatus) 
0x0000022d4109f643 (Mono JIT Code) [DummyClient.cs:52] GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.DummyClient:Authenticate (bool,System.Action`1<GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.SignInStatus>) 
0x0000022d4109f103 (Mono JIT Code) [PlayGamesPlatform.cs:438] GooglePlayGames.ISocialPlatform.PlayGamesPlatform:Authenticate (GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.SignInInteractivity,System.Action`1<GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.SignInStatus>) 
0x0000022d4109eaab (Mono JIT Code) [GooglePlayServices.cs:61] Managers.GooglePlayServices:Login () 
0x0000022d4109e71b (Mono JIT Code) [LaunchSceneHandler.cs:47] UI.Launch_Scene.LaunchSceneHandler/<SceneLoadCoroutine>d__4:MoveNext () 
0x0000022d4109e4ac (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator,intptr)
0x0000022d4109e5d7 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_object_intptr (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007ffa5341e660 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2816] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ffa533a2ae2 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2921] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ffa533abb3f (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2968] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff6a5e2f0f4 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff6a5e275f5 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff6a5dc37cf (Unity) Coroutine::Run
0x00007ff6a5ddf7ce (Unity) MonoBehaviour::TryCreateAndRunCoroutine
0x00007ff6a5dddf63 (Unity) MonoBehaviour::StartCoroutineManaged2
0x00007ff6a600e5a4 (Unity) MonoBehaviour_CUSTOM_StartCoroutineManaged2
0x0000022d4109e386 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutineManaged2 (UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour,System.Collections.IEnumerator)
0x0000022d4109e0c3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine (System.Collections.IEnumerator)
0x0000022d4109dfa3 (Mono JIT Code) [LaunchSceneHandler.cs:29] UI.Launch_Scene.LaunchSceneHandler:Start () 
0x0000022c6fb55a30 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007ffa5341e660 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2816] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ffa533a2ae2 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2921] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ffa533abb3f (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2968] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff6a5e2f0f4 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff6a5e275f5 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff6a5dd8d3d (Unity) MonoBehaviour::InvokeMethodOrCoroutineChecked
0x00007ff6a5dd8e68 (Unity) MonoBehaviour::InvokeMethodOrCoroutineChecked
0x00007ff6a5dd3bf2 (Unity) MonoBehaviour::DelayedStartCall
0x00007ff6a5294b64 (Unity) DelayedCallManager::Update
0x00007ff6a5707ec9 (Unity) `InitPlayerLoopCallbacks'::`2'::EarlyUpdateScriptRunDelayedStartupFrameRegistrator::Forward
0x00007ff6a56e962c (Unity) ExecutePlayerLoop
0x00007ff6a56e9703 (Unity) ExecutePlayerLoop
0x00007ff6a56f0539 (Unity) PlayerLoop
0x00007ff6a6b469c1 (Unity) PlayerLoopController::UpdateScene
0x00007ff6a6b2c45f (Unity) PlayerLoopController::EnterPlayMode
0x00007ff6a6b41b6d (Unity) PlayerLoopController::SetIsPlaying
0x00007ff6a6b43b09 (Unity) Application::TickTimer
0x00007ff6a74dd5d1 (Unity) MainMessageLoop
0x00007ff6a74e1611 (Unity) WinMain
0x00007ff6a93369b6 (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007ffae12c54e0 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007ffae260485b (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution was found in my case, the point was that I was refactoring the entire solution, which moved the entire `Plugins/Demigiant/DOTween/Modules/` folder (where the modules were located) to the namespace corresponding to its location, that is, to the namespace `Plugins.Demigiant.DOTween.Modules` before that they were in their `DG.Tweening` namespace, changing it back to DG.Tweening I was able to get rid of the problem.

Be vigilant when changing namespaces in plugins and services, I'm still understanding this.